# How do I update null cells based on the non-null cells from the same column using case statements?

Tags: sql, postgresql, conditional-statements, case

I'm new to SQL, and I tried searching online for a similar post to my problem but came up empty. So here goes.

I have a table `t1` that collates survey responses with the following columns: `date`, `id`, `group`, and `level`. There are more columns but these are basically the ones I'm concerned with. The first 3 columns tell me who answered the survey and when (there's a many to many relationship between the `id` and `group` column values). There is at most 1 entry for each `id`-`group` combination in each month (with the date value pegged on the first day of the month). The `level` column is their response to the survey.

For each existing pair of `id` and `group`, I want to get the `level` for each month from 2022 and 2023. The problem is, I have lots of gaps in that column. Take this small example:

date | id | group | level
2022-01-01 | 1 | A | null
2022-02-01 | 1 | A | 3
2022-03-01 | 1 | A | null
2022-04-01 | 1 | A | null
2022-05-01 | 1 | A | 4
2022-06-01 | 1 | A | 5
2022-07-01 | 1 | A | null

So, I want to extrapolate the data that I do have. For each row with a null `level`, I want to assign the `level` of the most recent non-null month prior to that "missing" month. If the row with the null value has no prior month with a non-null value (i.e. it's January 2022), get the value of the earliest month with a non-null `level` that occurs after the null row. So the desired output would be:

date | id | group | level
2022-01-01 | 1 | A | 3
2022-02-01 | 1 | A | 3
2022-03-01 | 1 | A | 3
2022-04-01 | 1 | A | 3
2022-05-01 | 1 | A | 4
2022-06-01 | 1 | A | 5
2022-07-01 | 1 | A | 5

My approach was like this:
I used a table `t2` to grab all the rows from `t1` with non-null `level` values. I then created CTE `t3` to basically be a duplicate of `t1`, with one extra column called `insert`. This new column will be where I put the extrapolated `t1.level` values and I'll use a simple update function to transfer `t3.insert` to the corresponding null `t1.level` rows.

```
with t3 as 
    Select distinct t1.date, t1.id, t1.group, t1.level,
    Case
--for when the null t1 record is earlier than the earliest t2 record
        When (t2.date = (select min(t2.date) where (t1.id, t1.group) = (t2.id, t2.group)))
        Then t2.level
--when the null t1 record is later than some existing t2 record
        When (t2.date = (select max(t2.date) where (t1.id, t1.group) = (t2.id, t2.group) AND t2.date <= t1.date))
        Then t2.level
        Else null
    End as "insert"
    from t1
    Join t2 on (t1.id, t1.group) = (t2.id, t2.group)
    GROUP BY t1.date, t1.id, t1.group, t1.level, t2.id, t2.group, t2.date, t2.level
    ORDER BY t1.id, t1.group, t1.date
)
```

I couldn't even get to the part where I update `t1.level` because I ran into a problem. I found that for every pair of `id` and `group`, `t3` was assigning every `t2.level` value to each `t3.insert`. For the January 2022 record for `id` = 1 and `group` = A:

date | id | group | level | insert
2022-01-01 | 1 | A | null | 3
2022-01-01 | 1 | A | null | 4
2022-01-01 | 1 | A | null | 5

It seems like postgresql is ignoring the min() function in my case statement. I probably made a really rookie mistake.

Comment: You should look at window functions (specifically ROW_NUMBER()). This would help in this regard. 

Because you're wanting to look backwards and forwards for the first possible date I don't really have the time to write an example for you.

Have a play around with this function, as it might help. Your query will turn out quite complex due to both having to look to the past and future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query demonstrates an approach for determining the substitution values for NULL survey levels by finding the prior non-NULL level, or if none exists, then the next non-NULL level.

```
WITH t1(survey_date, id, survey_group, survey_level) AS (
  VALUES ('2022-01-01'::date, 1, 'A', null),
         ('2022-02-01'::date, 1, 'A', 3),
         ('2022-03-01'::date, 1, 'A', null),
         ('2022-04-01'::date, 1, 'A', null),
         ('2022-05-01'::date, 1, 'A', 4),
         ('2022-06-01'::date, 1, 'A', 5),
         ('2022-07-01'::date, 1, 'A', null)
)
SELECT t1.survey_date, t1.id, t1.survey_group, t1.survey_level,
       COALESCE(t1.survey_level,
                -- prior non-NULL level
                (array_agg(t1.survey_level)
                   FILTER (WHERE t1.survey_level IS NOT NULL)
                   OVER (PARTITION BY t1.id, t1.survey_group
                         ORDER BY t1.survey_date DESC
                         ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING))[1],
                -- next non-NULL level
                (array_agg(t1.survey_level)
                   FILTER (WHERE t1.survey_level IS NOT NULL)
                   OVER (PARTITION BY t1.id, t1.survey_group
                         ORDER BY t1.survey_date
                         ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING))[1]) AS substitute_level
  FROM t1
  ORDER BY t1.survey_date, t1.id, t1.survey_group;
```

The prior and next values are collected into arrays ordered such that the first element of the array is the nearest non-NULL value in the given direction. Because the prior values are sorted in descending order, the window frame is defined using `FOLLOWING` instead of `PRECEDING`.