# Postgres how to forward and backfill values in a calendar week

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have the following table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (
                                    date DATE,
                                    value INT
);

INSERT INTO test VALUES
                     ( '2022-01-11', NULL),  -- Tues
                     ( '2022-01-10', 5),  -- Mon
                     ( '2022-01-09', NULL),  -- Sun
                     ( '2022-01-08', 6),  -- Sat
                     ( '2022-01-07', NULL), -- Fri
                     ( '2022-01-06', NULL), -- Thur
                     ( '2022-01-05', 5), -- Wed
                     ( '2022-01-04', NULL), -- Tues
                     ( '2022-01-03', NULL), --Mon
                     ( '2022-01-02', NULL), -- Sun
                     ( '2022-01-01', NULL); -- Sat
```

What is a query that forward and backfills the value column, for calendar week (Monday through Sunday)

For a calendar week should forward fill null values up to the next non-null value, and backfill null values up to the previous non-null value. If the calendar week has all null values then the week should be null

The result should look like this:

| date | VALUES |
| --- | --- |
| '2021-01-11' | 5 -- Tues, filled from Monday |
| '2022-01-10' | 5 -- Mon |
| '2022-01-09' | 6 -- Sun Filled from saturday |
| '2022-01-08' | 6 -- Sat |
| '2022-01-07' | 5 -- Fri Filled from Wed |
| '2022-01-06' | 5 -- Thur Filled from Wed |
| '2022-01-05' | 5 -- Wed |
| '2022-01-04' | 5 -- Tues Filled from Wed |
| '2022-01-03' | 5 --Mon Filled from Wed |
| '2022-01-02' | Null -- Sun |
| '2022-01-01' | Null -- Sat No values in week, therefor null |

Comment: Please see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76504821/how-do-i-update-null-cells-based-on-the-non-null-cells-from-the-same-column-usin/76521167#76521167) to a similar problem. One change that you will need is to partition the `array_agg` functions by week.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would have been a good spot for `last_value` with option `ignore nulls`, but unfortunately Postgres does not support the latter.

Here is one way to do it in Postgres with window functions:

```
select date, value,
    max(value) over(partition by date_trunc('week', date), grp) new_value
from (
    select t.*,
        count(value) over(partition by date_trunc('week', date) order by date) grp
    from test t
) t
order by date desc
```

The approach is to build groups of consecutive rows of the same week that contain a non-null value, possibly followed by null values, using a window `count`, and then bring the latest previous non-null value. You can run the subquery separately to see how groups are built.

---

If you also want the query to look for the *next* value when no previous value is availability in the same week, we can just expand the logic and define two groups for each row, then try both:

```
select date, value,
    coalesce(
        max(value) over(partition by date_trunc('week', date), grp1),
        max(value) over(partition by date_trunc('week', date), grp2)
    ) new_value
from (
    select t.*,
        count(value) over(partition by date_trunc('week', date) order by date     ) grp1,
        count(value) over(partition by date_trunc('week', date) order by date desc) grp2
    from test t
) t
order by date desc
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/U3rxl4AW)**

Comment: The 1st method you're suggesting creates null values on the 4th and 3rd. The 2nd one does work though.

Answer (score 0):

This query looks for the next or previous non-null value within the same week (or in the following week if there is no non-null value in the same week) for each date in the table, and uses it to fill any null value.

The query builds the groups by first partitioning the data by week, and then constructs a window frame within each group to find the next or previous non-null value.

```sql
SELECT date,
       value,
       COALESCE(value,
-- prior non-NULL value
                (ARRAY_AGG(value)
                 FILTER (WHERE value IS NOT NULL)
                     OVER (PARTITION BY DATE_TRUNC('week', date)
                     ORDER BY date DESC
                     ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING))[1],
-- next non-NULL value
                (ARRAY_AGG(value) FILTER (WHERE value IS NOT NULL) OVER
                    (PARTITION BY DATE_TRUNC('week', date)
                    ORDER BY date ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING))[1]
           ) AS substitute_level
FROM test
ORDER BY date DESC;
```

Demo on [db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/an7L7mT1)

Comment: This query will only look within a single week for substitute values because of `PARTITION BY DATE_TRUNC('week', date)`, not "in the following week if there is no non-null value in the same week." Each week's aggregations are unaffected by values in adjacent weeks.